# How to install FreeBASIC?

Tags: freebasic

I installed FreeBasic under Ubuntu 14 using the provided shell installer,
and received a message that the installation was successful.

But, when I attempt to run the compiler it gives a list of missing `-dev` files,
only two of which I was able to locate in repositories.

The installation README indicates that some of the listed dependencies may have different names in some Linux dialects.

How do I locate the missing dependencies in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The FreeBASIC wiki (specifically, http://freebasic.net/wiki/DevBuildLinux) describes how to get FB to compile on Linux, and suggests the following packages:

- gcc
- make
- libncurses5-dev
- libgpm-dev
- libx11-dev
- libxext-dev
- libxpm-dev
- libxrandr-dev
- libxrender-dev
- libgl1-mesa-dev
- libffi-dev

You can install them all in one command with:

```
sudo apt install gcc make lib{ncurses5,gpm,x11,xext,xpm,xrandr,xrender,gl1-mesa,ffi}-dev
```

Some of the packages may only be needed if you actually plan to build the FreeBASIC compiler and runtime libraries from scratch.  But they are at least sufficient for getting programs to compile and run with fbc.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of googling for freeBASIC dependencies , this might help

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxrender-dev:i386 libxrandr-dev:i386 libxpm-dev:i386
```